# Animated simulation using SVG

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I am interested in doing simple simulations using SVG. The examples I have seen for SVG animations, however, just seem to have a play and loop capability. To render my simulation I want to be able to jump to any particular frame, like you can do in a video player. Also, ideally, I would like to be able to play or step the simulation backwards from any given point. To summarize I am looking for the following capabilities:

1. Ability to play animation at different speeds
2. Ability to select any individual frame in the animation
3. Ability to play forwards or backwards from the selected frame
4. Ability to pause the animation

I normally am planning to run the SVG out of a Java environment using either TinyLine, Salamander or Batik (any opinions about which is better btw); however, in some circumstances I may want to run the simulation in a browser, where I assume I will need some kind of Javascript VCR control system.

Is what I am envisioning possible with SVG?

Comment: YES, indeed! Javascript is a cool language, dive in, it offers great features but if you are not familiar with it, you might feel a bit uncomfortable with it the first days…

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to take a look at [GSAP](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/) which provides all the features that you need. It can control HTML, canvas or SVG animations.